# drag images in a table - fix size and each image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image]
I want to be able to drag every single image and to go them where ever I like.I can not.I try to do it but I failed many times.Also,I don't know why my table is not standar is increasing his size(width and height).I want a standar  table ,that is changing when I drag the image.Also I am not able to move all the images I insert them. Here is the javascript code

```
 $(function() {
    initDragAndDrop();
    $('#addRow').on('click', function() {
      $('#targetTable > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
      clearDragAndDrop();
      initDragAndDrop();
    });
  });

  function clearDragAndDrop() {
    $('.event').off();
    $('table td').off('dragenter dragover drop');
  }

  function initDragAndDrop() {
    $('.event').on('dragstart', function(event) {
      var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
      dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
    });
    $('table td').on('dragenter dragover drop', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (event.type === 'drop') {
        var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
        de = $('#' + data).detach();
        de.appendTo($(this));
      }
    });
  }
```

the .css code

```
table span {
  display: block;
  background-color: #09C;
  height: 1%;
  width: 200%;
  text-align: top;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 1px;
}
```

the code in body is this -the way I created my table

```
 <table  id="targetTable" class="b" border="10" bordercolor="blue" style="width: 100%" height="10%" id="myT" >
            <tbody><tr>
            
                   <td> 1</td>
                   <td> 2</td>
                  <td> 3</td>
                   <td> 4</td>
                   <td> 5</td>
                   <td> 6</td>
                   <td> 7</td>
                   <td> 8</td>
                   <td> 9</td>
                   <td> 10</td>
                   <td> 11</td>
                   <td style="width: 5px; height: 1px;">12 
                   <br>
                   
  <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">         a <img  src="./images/P2R.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%" ></span>  
                   <br>
     <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">             b <img   src="./images/P2R.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span>
                   <br>
    <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">             c<img       src="./images/P2R.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span>
                   <br>
    <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">               d<img      src="./images/P2R.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span>
                   <br>
    <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">               e<img class="dragme"         src="./images/P2R.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span>
                   <br>
    <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">               f<img  class="dragme"       src="./images/P2R.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span>
                   <br>
    <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">               g<img class="dragme"         src="./images/P2R.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span>
                   <br>
    <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">               h<img class="dragme"         src="./images/P2R.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span>
                   <br>
    <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">               i<img  class="dragme"       src="./images/P2R.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span>
                   <br>
    <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">               k<img   class="dragme"      src="./images/P2R.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span>
                   <br>
    <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">               l<img  class="dragme"       src="./images/P2R.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span>
                   <br>
    <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">               m<img  class="dragme"       src="./images/P2R.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span>
                   <br>
    <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">               n<img class="dragme"        src="./images/P2R.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span>
                   <br>
        <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">           o<img class="dragme"        src="./images/P2R.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span>
                   <br>
    <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">               p<img class="dragme"        src="./images/P2R.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span>
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   </td>
                   
                        </tr>
                        
                        <td> 24
                        
                        
                               
                   <br>
                       
<span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">                   a <img  id="dragme"        src="./images/P1B.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span
                   <br>
<span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">                   b <img  id="dragme"            src="./images/P1B.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span
                   <br>
    <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">               c<img id="dragme"                      src="./images/P1B.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span
                   <br>
<span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">                   d<img  class="dragme"                    src="./images/P1B.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span
                   <br>
    <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">               e<img  class="dragme"                   src="./images/P1B.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span
                   <br>
    <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">               f<img class="dragme"                            src="./images/P1B.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span
                   <br>
    <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">               g<img    class="dragme" src="./images/P1B.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span
                   <br>
    <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">               h<img class="dragme"          src="./images/P1B.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span
                   <br>
    <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">               i<img    class="dragme" src="./images/P1B.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span
                   <br>
    <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">               k<img class="dragme"                 src="./images/P1B.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span
                   <br>
    <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">               l<img class="dragme"                 src="./images/P1B.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span
                   <br>
    <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">               m<img class="dragme"  src="./images/P1B.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span
                   <br>
    <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">               n<img class="dragme"               src="./images/P1B.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span
                   <br>
    <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">               o<img  class="dragme"          src="./images/P1B.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%">
                   <br>
    <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">               p<img class="dragme"     src="./images/P1B.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%">
                   
                   
                   
                    
                        </td>
                   <td> 23</td>
                   <td> 22</td>
                   <td> 21</td>
                   <td> 20</td>
                   <td> 19</td>
                   <td> 18</td>
                   <td> 17</td>
                   <td> 16</td>
                   <td> 15</td>
                   <td> 14</td>
                   
                   <td> 13
                   
                 
                   </td>
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   
                  
   

    
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>








  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given same `id` for all your `span` tag so your code is not able to find correctly from where to remove image .Instead of that you can use `data-attribute` and give some unique class to your td where these images are located. Then , you can simply use this `class` and `data-id` to detach any element whenever it is dropped.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(function() {
  initDragAndDrop();
  $('#addRow').on('click', function() {
    $('#targetTable > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
    clearDragAndDrop();
    initDragAndDrop();
  });
});

function clearDragAndDrop() {
  $('.event').off();
  $('table td').off('dragenter dragover drop');
}

function initDragAndDrop() {
  $('.event').on('dragstart', function(event) {
    var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
    //add dat-attr and class from where to remove
    dt.setData('Text', $(this).data('id') + "," + $(this).closest("td").attr('class'));

  });
  $('table td').on('dragenter dragover drop', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.type === 'drop') {
      var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text').split(",");
      var data_id = data[0];
      var from_class_to_remove = data[1]
      //find td and span to remove
      de = $("." + from_class_to_remove + "> span[data-id=" + data_id + "]").detach();
      de.appendTo($(this));
    }
  });
}
```

```css
td span {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #09C;
  font-weight: bold;
}

img {
  padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="targetTable" class="b" border="10" bordercolor="blue" id="myT">
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td> 1</td>
      <td> 2</td>
      <td> 3</td>
      <td> 4</td>
      <td> 5</td>
      <td> 6</td>
      <td> 7</td>
      <td> 8</td>
      <td> 9</td>
      <td> 10</td>
      <td> 11</td>
      <!--also give someclass to td here-->
      <td class="other">12
        <br>
        <!--use data-id-->
        <span class="event" data-id="a" draggable="true">a
        <img  src="https://i.imgur.com/ZEZLSOo.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%" ></span>
        <br>
        <span class="event" data-id="b" draggable="true">          b <img   src="https://i.imgur.com/ZEZLSOo.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span>
        <br>
        <span class="event" data-id="c" draggable="true">             c<img       src="https://i.imgur.com/ZEZLSOo.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span>
        <br>
        <span class="event" data-id="d" draggable="true">             d<img       src="https://i.imgur.com/ZEZLSOo.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span>
        <br>
        <span class="event" data-id="e" draggable="true">             e<img       src="https://i.imgur.com/ZEZLSOo.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span>
        <br>
        <span class="event" data-id="f" draggable="true">             f<img       src="https://i.imgur.com/ZEZLSOo.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span>
        <br>
        <span class="event" data-id="g" draggable="true">             g<img       src="https://i.imgur.com/ZEZLSOo.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span>
        <br>
        <span class="event" data-id="h" draggable="true">             h<img       src="https://i.imgur.com/ZEZLSOo.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span>
        <br>
        <span class="event" data-id="i" draggable="true">             i<img       src="https://i.imgur.com/ZEZLSOo.png" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span>


      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="other1"> 24
        <span class="event" data-id="a" draggable="true">                   a <img  id="dragme" src="https://i.imgur.com/dL3J8XS.jpeg" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span>
        <br/>
        <span class="event" data-id="b" draggable="true">                   b <img  id="dragme"            src="https://i.imgur.com/dL3J8XS.jpeg" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span>
        <br/>
        <span class="event" data-id="c" draggable="true">               c<img id="dragme"                      src="https://i.imgur.com/dL3J8XS.jpeg" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span> <br/>
        <span class="event" data-id="d" draggable="true">               d<img id="dragme"                      src="https://i.imgur.com/dL3J8XS.jpeg" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span> <br/>
        <span class="event" data-id="e" draggable="true">               e<img id="dragme"                      src="https://i.imgur.com/dL3J8XS.jpeg" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span> <br/>
        <span class="event" data-id="f" draggable="true">               f<img id="dragme"                      src="https://i.imgur.com/dL3J8XS.jpeg" class="b" alt="Norway" style="width:30%"></span>

      </td>
      <td> 23</td>
      <td> 22</td>
      <td> 21</td>
      <td> 20</td>
      <td> 19</td>
      <td> 18</td>
      <td> 17</td>
      <td> 16</td>
      <td> 15</td>
      <td> 14</td>
      <td> 13</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: if I add 15 instead of 3 (a,b,c) I get out of the table....that's the problem ,even with your code I face the same issue..

Comment: please elaborate what do you mean by `I get out of the table`  ?

Comment: so images are showing out of table you mean here ? that has to do with css :) sorry i am not too good in that .

Comment: its ok thats my issue

Comment: Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/h5b6rofx/) . let me know if this still didn't work.